# How to retrieve makeStatic or makeDynamic methods in LHBezier? LevelHelper - Cocos2D

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, levelhelper

In the LevelHelper, I am able to set bezier shapes to static, dynamic etc. In my code, I am in need of changing these properties. Can someone please help me with that?

```
LHBezier* bezier = [loader bezierWithUniqueName:@"BezierNode"];

[bezier makeStatic]; // not working
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change body type like this:

```
bezier.body->SetType(b2_staticBody);
bezier.body->SetType(b2_dynamicBody);
bezier.body->SetType(b2_kinematicBody);
```